# id PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT começando do 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Antes ao realizar este código:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(50),
    descricao varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

ao colocar o primeiro elemento id começava no 0. Porém por algum motivo, do nada agora ele está iniciando do 1, queria saber o que ocorreu e se tem como fazer começar do 0.

Answer (score 0):

### Iniciar o auto incremento 0 não é o padrão *MySQL*

As variáveis ​​de sistema [`auto_increment_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-source.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) e [`auto_increment_offset`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-source.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) destinam-se ao uso com replicação de origem e sendo usadas ​​para controlar a operação de `AUTO_INCREMENT` nas colunas das tabelas. Onde:

- `auto_increment_increment` controla o intervalo entre os valores sucessivos da coluna.
- `auto_increment_offset` determina o ponto inicial para o valor de  auto incremento da coluna.

Ambas as variáveis ​​têm valores globais e de sessão, e cada uma pode assumir um valor inteiro entre `1` e `65535` inclusive. Sendo que:

- Definir o valor de qualquer uma dessas duas variáveis ​​como `0` faz com que seu valor seja definido como `1`.
- A tentativa de definir o valor de qualquer uma dessas duas variáveis ​​como um número inteiro maior que `65535` ou inteiro menor que `0` faz com que seu valor seja definido como `65535`.
- Tentar definir o valor de `auto_increment_increment` ou `auto_increment_offset` para um valor não inteiro produz um erro e o valor atual da variável permanece inalterado.

### Contorno com o Modo de Operação SQL

Segundo essas duas publicações [Mysql - how to set auto-increment to start from zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16232430/11379709) e [How to force *MySQL* to take 0 as a valid auto-increment value](https://serverfault.com/q/42071/570528) você pode modificar o [Modo de Operação SQL do Servidor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-sql-modes.html) configurando a variável de sistema [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) com valor [`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero):

```sql
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

Os modos SQL do servidor definem qual sintaxe SQL o MySQL deve suportar e que tipo de verificações de validação de dados ele deve executar.
Os administradores podem definir o modo SQL global para corresponder aos requisitos operacionais do servidor do site, e cada aplicativo pode definir seu modo SQL de sessão para seus próprios requisitos.

Como modo não está vinculado a um banco de dados específico. Os modos podem ser definidos localmente para a sessão (conexão) ou globalmente para o servidor onde são observadas algumas ressalvas:

- Se você usa **`GLOBAL`**, não será realizada uma mudança imediata, você precisa reiniciar sua conexão para aplicar a configuração.
- Use **`SESSION`** para uma alteração imediata. Porém quando encerrar a sessão, ao reiniciar ou ao fechar a conexão, a configuração será desfeita e o comportamento padrão será aplicado a próxima sessão.

### Pratica não recomendada

Segundo a documentação `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` afeta o manuseio de `AUTO_INCREMENT` colunas. Normalmente, é gerado o próximo número de sequência para a coluna inserindo um `NULL` ou `0`. `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` esse comportamento é suprimido para o `0` onde apenas `NULL` gere o próximo número de sequência.
Porém problemas serão encontrados pois se despejar a tabela com [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) e depois recarregá-la, o *MySQL* normalmente gera novos números de sequência quando encontra valores `0`, resultando em uma tabela com conteúdo diferente daquele que foi despejado e a ativação do modo `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` antes de recarregar o arquivo de despejo deverá ser feita.

Valores de auto incremento `0` não são recomendados para serem usados, pois como dito não são definidos como padrão em bancos de dados *MySQL* além de que em muitas linguagens de programação possuem funções que interpretam `0` como false o pode levar a erros lógicos de difícil detecção.

Answer (score -1):

Mesmo deletando os dados da tabela se não me engano ele n reseta o auto increment, acho que isso deve ajudar:

```
ALTER TABLE NmTabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
```

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: Do manual: "Note: ALTER TABLE ... AUTO_INCREMENT = N can only change the auto-increment counter value to a value larger than the current maximum." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization

Comment: Na documentação tbm tem essa parte: "For example, you might try to set the counter value to a lesser value after deleting some records. In this case, the table must be searched to ensure that the new counter value is not less than or equal to the actual current maximum counter value."

No caso não seria limpar a tabela antes de aplicar o comando? eu to sem MySQL instalado pra testar :/